# Cannot overwrite product list template in catalog_category_view

Tags: magento2, layout

I am trying to overwrite this template from a custom module but nothing at all is working. I've tried arguments to set the template... I've messed with sequence.

Below is the code in Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="catalog_category_view"/>

    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Elcometer_Quote::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

This will not work, it is placed: app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

We need to declare nodes: `<action method="setTemplate">` and `<update handle="catalog_category_view"/>` in your layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <update handle="catalog_category_view"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Elcometer_Quote::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Why touch catalog_product_view? I'm trying to modify the category view.

Comment: Yes, try with `<update handle="catalog_category_view"/>`.

Comment: So I'm using update handle catalog_category_view in my module/catalog_category_view.xml layout file?

Could you explain the logic behind that?

Comment: Updated, nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `<action method="setTemplate">` tag:

```
<referenceBlock name="search_result_list">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Elcometer_Quote::html/topmenu.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Testing now....

Comment: That didn't work, I cleared cache too.

I am getting some merged layout INFO errors.

Comment: Updated with my layout code.

Comment: Should I be targeting search_result_list or was that an example?

Comment: Yes, the only part that should change is the template file being referenced. I tested that code and it should work.

Comment: So if I want to change on a category page I should be targeting search_result_list?

Comment: No, that was specific to your other question.

Comment: I'm confused, my whole question is about changing the category page. All I want to do is change the template for the product list.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem was trying to target catalog_category_view, the page I was attempting to manipulate the product list block could only be modified by catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml.**

If anyone could further explain this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Additionally, I now have a problem where a method that the template wants to use isn't available on that template.

Comment: So did you find a solution?
For your other concern, please open a new question.

Comment: Yes, I did I will make it bold.

Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you trying to change template of the "category.products" instead of "category.products.list". Your code should be like this:

```
    <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Elcometer_Quote::product/list.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```