# overwrite default product list with help of extension

Tags: magento2, extensions, frontend

I want to add content in product list page. For this i followed [creating extension for product list](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148680/use-product-list-template-with-my-own-product-collection)

For example here http://localhost/magento_ce222/women/tops-women/jackets-women.html i want some content / block in each product. I can able to add block in product detail page. With this link [amasty helloworld extension](https://amasty.com/blog/how-to-create-a-magento-2-extension/)

This link also helped. But i cant find solution
[Cannot overwrite product list template in catalog_category_view](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132480/cannot-overwrite-product-list-template-in-catalog-category-view)

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake!
I didnt created di.xml in etc folder. This link [Add custom block on listing page : Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96642/add-custom-block-on-listing-page-magento2) helped me to solve